# Efficiently display large list of images in multiple rows and columns in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, jquery-lazyload

I am trying to display a list of 1000+ images in Blazor, while keeping it as performant as possible.
The items are displayed in rows, and depending on the size of the browser, the images will become larger/smaller, and the amount of items/row will change.
As of now, the images are loaded in a container with some CSS that sets a width the width of the image and gives it float left, meaning all the images automatically pop up next to each other.
I have the full list of images in my frontend, so I'm not taking from my backend as needed for now.

I would like to display all images in for example 2x my viewport, but not load all the elements that come after.
[image: Example of how list would look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPTcr.png)

I have tried to use the  component, but that does not seem to work well with having multiple items per row, since this assumes 1 element per row.

Since at the very least I did not want to load all the images at once, I am currently lazyload.js to prevent the images from loading, displaying an empty image if it is not near the viewport. This is not exactly the solution I want however, since I am still adding 1000+ elements to my DOM, causing a delay of a couple of seconds.

Optimally, I would like to have something like the  Component, where I can just give my items, say how many extra rows of images or viewport heights should be loaded, without having to give the height of the items or the amount of columns per row.

Comment: Does this help ? Component virtualisation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Have you tried `<img loading="lazy" src=".... />` you dont need js. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AActXSWxsRo

Comment: @Brian Parker Geez man, that's a thing?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading

Comment: Nice.  I'm in Korea, and I can literally load 1000 images in about 10 seconds, but it means that nobody in the US can use the image of my site.

Comment: Hey Brian, I noticed you were very close to 10,000 points, so I went back and upped a couple of your recent posts to get you over the finish line.  Grats on 10k and thanks for all the great input over the past year.  Happy 2023!

Comment: @GaëlJames That is the component I have already tried using: the issue with that component is that it seems to be unable to work together with items that display multiple columns of items.  I did not manage to get it to work after playing around with it.

Comment: @BrianParker I have not tried that, but I also think this is simply a replacement for my current (hacky) solution, where I use the JS lazyload library. I will try it though, it seems like a better way to do it. I think this won't fix my main problem though, where it simply takes my computer/phone quite some time to load > 1000 blazor components to the DOM.

Comment: You need to virtualize, not 1 image, but an entire row of images.

Comment: I'd suggest using JS interop to retrieve the viewport width, thereby you know how many images each row contains. Finally, transform the list of images into a list of list of images (list of rows). `Enumerable.Range(0,nbRows).Select(r => images.Skip(r*nbImgPerRow).Take(nbImgPerRow).ToList()).ToList()`

Comment: In the example I gave I simplified my requirements, but I'm now not sure if I should have: Instead of simply displaying 1000+ images, I'm displaying a dynamic amount of groups, eg. 4 groups of 250 images. Each group has a header, and is collapsible. I tried to put a Virtualize block in each group iterating the rows of images, calculating how many items fit in a row and how tall the row is. However, since the Virtualize needs to be in a fixed height container which is scrollable,  I would see the next group, while still being able to scroll in the previous, which was not desirable.